# Parse diff output with Java

Tags: java, regex, diff

I am developing an app with JavaFX that compares two files and I am getting such outputs like in column Nr. 3

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Usage

Column Nr.3 shows the differences between column 1 and 2. Is there a way to do this? I could not find any libraries that could do that, and I thought maybe I can do this with regex, is that fine? or there is an easier way? so I can show the changes that have been made to files in a user friendly way.

*P.S. cannot insert the text in here because it is parsed in a strange way.*

Comment: Have you tried searching the library? Google shows me plenty of them, e.g. https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Comment: I am searching for a library that can read the output that I already have, not to do the same that I have done already, so no, not really what I want/need.

Comment: "Column Nr.3 shows the differences between column 1 and 2. Is there a way to do this?", - the library I've linked answers this. "a library that can read the output that I already have", - what kind of output? Can you please update your question, currently it is pretty unclear what do you want.

Comment: "I am developing an app with JavaFX that compares two files and I am getting such outputs like in column Nr. 3" - if you open the link, there you can see in column Nr. 3 is an output with diff showing the differences, so now I want to parse this syntax, so I can display it in a user friendly way to users. I hope now it's more clear :)